# Why is i386 packages installed on a 64bit system?

Tags: linux, centos

When I e.g. install MySQL on a x86_64 CentOS, `yum` wants to install the i386 version as well.

Why does it do that? And can I just get the x86_64 version to save disk space?

```
[root@rt ~]# yum install mysql-server mysql

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.i386 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(DBI) for package: mysql
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
---> Package mysql-server.x86_64 0:5.0.77-4.el5_6.6 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL for package: mysql-server
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:3.0007-2.el5 set to be updated
---> Package perl-DBI.x86_64 0:1.52-2.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===================================================================================
 Package                Arch           Version                  Repository    Size
===================================================================================
Installing:
 mysql                  i386           5.0.77-4.el5_6.6         base         4.8 M
 mysql                  x86_64         5.0.77-4.el5_6.6         base         4.8 M
 mysql-server           x86_64         5.0.77-4.el5_6.6         base         9.8 M
Installing for dependencies:
 perl-DBD-MySQL         x86_64         3.0007-2.el5             base         148 k
 perl-DBI               x86_64         1.52-2.el5               base         600 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total download size: 20 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely the 32bit client only part that might be necessary for compability purposes with older 32bit only binary applications.

And even talking about saving 4.8 MB of disk space is not worth the time, IMHO.